# Is trace equal to 1 equivalent to free on one generator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, trace, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a f.g. projective module.
Is it true that if the trace of the identity map of $M$ is equal to 1, then $M \cong R$?

Comment: I think it is true. If M is a f.g. projective module, then M≅R^n for some n. So the trace of the identity map of M is equal to n. So n=1.

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi If $M$ was free then I agree on your argument, but I'm not following if $M$ is only projective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $M$ can be any f.g. projective module of rank $1$ (an invertible module / line bundle over $\text{Spec } R$). In this case $M$ is locally free of rank $1$, so that $M_P \cong R_P$ for any prime ideal $P$, meaning the trace of the identity on $M_P$ is locally equal to $1$. I have to admit I don't remember enough commutative algebra to know off the top of my head what the kernel of localization at every prime ideal is but under mild hypotheses, e.g. $R$ an integral domain but this is probably too strong, it follows that the trace of the identity on $M$ is equal to $1$. But I am pretty sure the trace of the identity is $1$ with no further hypotheses.

For a sillier counterexample, $R$ can have positive characteristic, in which case the trace of the identity does not determine the rank for free modules; for example if $R = \mathbb{F}_p$ then we can take $M = \mathbb{F}_p^{p+1}$.

Comment: Nice examples. To close the gap, the kernel of localization at all primes is trivial. If $x\in R$ is non-zero, the annihilator ideal $\mathrm{Ann}_R(x)$ is proper, so contained in a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and then $x$ has non-zero image in $R\rightarrow R_{\mathfrak{m}}$.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks! Something like this seemed like it ought to be true but I couldn't think of a proof or find a reference by googling.